# Code academy python "Battleship" - why is "none" printing after my grid?

Tags: python

This is a quickie. The assignment is to build a "Battleship" style grid of 0's.  My question is: why is "none" printing after my grid prints?  I could easily get through the assignment, but since I'm doing this to learn code I figured I would ask. Thanks!

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)  

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print '---'.join(row)

print_board(board)
```

Comment: I just executed this code and got five lines of `O---O---O---O---O`. What's wrong with this?

Comment: It's not. I tested your code and it works fine http://ideone.com/9SfZUD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did the module for myself on Codecademy. I can see why you got confused, the instructions are pretty confusing.

They really want you to do this:

```
board = []

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)
```

The `"---".join(row)` was an example showing you how to use join with characters. The instructions on the left side then ask you to use `" ".join(row)` in the example.

Codecademy automatically prints `None` at the end of each output for no apparent reason and if you use the `" ".join(row)` it will be correct with this output:

```
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
None
```

Comment: While I am very grateful to Codeacademy for getting me back to coding and being the most user-friendly game-fied version out there, the instructors(and their instructions!) vary quite a bit from exercise to exercise....makes it more... exciting?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are actually doing:

```
print print_board(board)
```

The `None` is because your function does not return anything. You can add a `return 1` under the  line `print '---'.join(row)` but outside the `for` loop and execute again to see what happens.

[EDIT] - This answer assumed that the python interpreter was used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting

```
>>> 
O---O---O---O---O
O---O---O---O---O
O---O---O---O---O
O---O---O---O---O
O---O---O---O---O
>>>
```

Which appears to be right? The code you have seems correct, with no additional none print.

Answer (score 2):

Because on the Codeacademy website, it automatically adds 'None' to the end of the code output to show you that there were no errors.

It does this in all of the Python tutorials.